# require function doesn't work inside a function within a method

Tags: node.js, http, server, backend, bcrypt

I'm using Node.js to build the back-end of an application and I'm using postgresql as database. I'm having problem with the implementation of the login. More precisely I am using the bcrypt module and it doesn't work in the function called by the execution of the query. Here is the code:

```
const login = async (request, response) => {
  const username = request.body.username

  console.log(request.body)

  pool.query('SELECT * FROM public."User" WHERE username = \'{' + username + '}\'', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      return response.status(400).send("Cannot find user: "+username)
    }
    try {
      if(await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, results.rows[0].password.toString())) {
        response.send('Success')
      } else {
        response.send('Not allowed')
      }
    } catch {
      response.status(500).send("Server error")
    }
  })
}
```

The problem is that I execute my query and it works, but when it arrives in the second if statement the problem is this:

```
 if(await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, results.rows[0].password.toString())) {
               ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Did you require/loading bcrypt as described in https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt ?

Comment: Yes it works outside (error, result) => {}

Comment: Just an idea: try to use the callback version of bcrypt compare instead of the await-statement...

Comment: What is the callback version?

Comment: I have solved it by adding "async" before (error, result)

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to take the try/catch statement outside the pool.query function, by saving the retrieved password in a variable, as follows:

```
const login = async (request, response) => {
  const username = request.body.username
  var hashedPassword

  console.log(request.body)

  pool.query('SELECT * FROM public."User" WHERE username = \'{' + username + '}\'', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      return response.status(400).send("Cannot find user: "+username)
    }
    hashedPassword = results.rows[0].password.toString()
  })

  try {
    if(await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, hashedPassword)) {
      response.send('Success')
    } else {
      response.send('Not allowed')
    }
  } catch {
    response.status(500).send("Server error")
  }
}
```

But in this way the try/catch statement is executed before the query and actually I don't even know if variable "hashedPassword" can be set in such a way, because I always find it as "undefined"